# Храм Святителя Николая Чудотворца. Везде заглавные?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется название храма? С заглавной?

Answer (score 1):

В Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. Лопатина (2007) в § 186 говорится, что в названиях монастырей, храмов, икон пишутся с прописной буквы все слова, кроме родовых наименований (*церковь, храм, собор, лавра, монастырь, семинария, икона,  образ*) и служебных слов, напр.: *Казанский собор, собор Парижской Богоматери, собор Святого Петра, Киево-Печерская лавра, храм Зачатия Праведной Анны, храм Всех Святых, храм Христа Спасителя, храм Святого Димитрия Ростовского, церковь  Николы в Кленниках, икона Донской Божией Матери, образ Знамения Божией Матери*.
Таким образом, нужно писать *храм Святителя Николая Чудотворца*.

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя в справочнике "Прописная или строчная?" рекомендуется  слово Святителя писать по-разному: святитель Григорий Богослов и храм Святителя Николая. Надо полагать, что в названиях пишется это слово с прописной буквы.